# Subtracting and getting values which are not in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe one

```
query
----------
A
B
C
D
E
```

dataframe two

```
query
---------
A
B
C
```

I want the output as

```
query
------------
D
E
```

as I want the values in one that are not in two

I have tried to convert it into lists and subtracting the values but that does not work.

Comment: Using isin here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df1[~df1['query'].isin(df2['query'])]
```